# Codename one: whole screen pushes downwords when showing toastbar

Tags: codenameone

When I shows toastbar on screen whole screen goes downwords with all containers pushes downwords all components allignment get chaged.It happens only when I shows toastbar on screen otherwise everything is fine.
Can you please let me know how to resolve it?
thanks in advance

Comment: How are you calling the ToasBar? This might be a bug.

Comment: ToastBar.Status status = ToastBar.getInstance().createStatus();
  status.setMessage(msg);
  status.setExpires(sec);
  status.setShowProgressIndicator(flag);   
  status.show()

Comment: thats how i calling the ToastBar

Comment: If you rotate the device or simulator does it produce a similar effect? What sort of layout or hierarchy do you use on the form. Did you override any of the following in your theme: `includeNativeBool`, `Container`?

Comment: Yes if i rotate the device  or simulator it produced same effect.i used border layout and value of includeNativeBool = true

Comment: Any solution...